# Can MPMoviePlayerController play m3u8 file

Tags: objective-c, ffmpeg, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play a m3u8 file using MPMovieplayercontroller
i pass the url to the MPMovieplayercontroller
But it will not play. Is it possible?

I am converting flv,avi video file formats into m3u8 files using ffmpeg for live http streaming on my server.

The m3u8 url works when i pass it to VLC as a network stream on my mac.
I know this has been asked a number of times but i have not got any satisfactory answers.

Regards
Nitesh

Comment: Yes, it works. Apple has (had?) some .m3u8 samples on their site, you should try playing them to see if the problem is with your player or with your ffmpeg output.

Comment: yes will the media player still play the m3u8 files irrespective of the video file formats i.e flv/mkv?? I originally thought the output of FFMPEG might be faulty but it does work on the VLC ios app when i pass the same url to it